# off canvas responsive menu flicker on page load - js and bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create a Wordpress site that includes off canvas menu for navigation. I've created a theme using bootstrap 3 and a jquery off-canvas menu plugin called Flexmenu. It works well but i'm getting non styled navigation elements loading momentarily - a 'flicker' effect during the time that the js calculates view port width and adds specific selector terms to the navigation's 'menu' div: 'fm-lg' for >767px and 'fm-sm' for <768px. Each selector added by the js generates appropriate navigation styling for the device width detected: off canvas for mobile devices (fm-sm) and standard nav for PC (fm-lg). The flickering is caused, I guess by the fact that the js is loaded after the pages html. (as the flexmenu js is called in the footer). Is there an efficient way to eliminate this issue (reorder the js, or style the navigation to be hidden until page load is completed) - as I don't have the skills to re-wrire the menu script! see: http://www.hyve.com.au/hyvemain

Comment: I can't see any "flickering" with the navigation on the link provided by you..

Comment: I see a flash of unstyled content with the menu. Try window load instead of document ready for the the menu. Also the use of col-xs-12 is not necessary, remove that class and you'll get the same result. It's always full width under the smallest column class you used.

Comment: Thanks Christina! - good point re: the col-xs-12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid the 'non styled' navigation to ' flicker' - use css to hide the navigation elements in the core css, until the js loads the responsive classes. Add a declaration to the responsive css to override the 'hide' property in the core css. So you'll ave hidden navigation elements until your js is fully loaded and available.